# XY event source layer problem (converts into feature class after running python script ) in ArcMap 10.1

Tags: python, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1

I am using ESRI 10.1 suit (ArcGIS Desktop & ArcGIS Server, No ArcSDE) at my end and after running python script n number of times event layer converts into feature class.

Following steps I am following :

-I am using query layer in ArcMap & fetching records from MS sql server, table type is plane table.

-Created XY event source layer from query layer and displaying points on the map.

-layer is classified using unique value symbology.

-My query layer is updating five times in day and using [python script (example2)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000005s000000) to automate the unique value symbology (using windows scheduler) five times in day.

-Overwriting mxd on ArcGIS Server 10.1  using ArcPy in specific time interval.

-After 10 times my XY event source is automatically converts to feature class then I am not able to use ArcPy script to update the legend at my end

So is there any bug related to XY event source layer or am I doing something wrong??

Researching on Google and ArcGIS web help not getting any reason/limitation for that.

Any help will be great !! thanks in advance !!

**EDIT :**

[Legend update python script](http://jsfiddle.net/keycg/)

[Map service overwrite script](http://jsfiddle.net/Mb3kc/)

[image: Screen-shot]

Comment: @Sunii, Can you post your code?

Comment: @artwork21 updated the question